# Unable to update table in PostgreSQL with Django due to deadlock

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, django-orm

I have a cron job that runs a Django management command every minute. When the command starts, it sets a flag `is_running = true` in a table stored in a PostgreSQL database (using pgbouncer as a connection pool). This flag is also checked by future processes to prevent re-running the same task while it's currently running.

One day I noticed the system was very slow, so running `ps aux | grep manage.py` showed hundreds of these processes, seemingly doing nothing.

So then I ran `ps aux|grep -i postgres` and I saw an equally large number of lines like:

```
postgres: dbuser dbname 127.0.0.1(47095) UPDATE waiting
```

Querying `pg_stat_activity` shows the query running the one to update `is_running = true`:

```
UPDATE "myapp_job" SET "is_running" = true WHERE "myapp_job"."id" = 32
```

This is effectively a very slow memory leak which is also consuming all my database connections. As a stop-gap, I've been killing the hanging postgres processes performing the updates that never complete, but this doesn't fix the underlying issue.

Why isn't this simple query not completing? It seems to be deadlocked, but I don't see why. Nothing else locks that table, other than the other update queries, but none of them should take more than a few milliseconds.

Also, why aren't the queries timing out? I've encountered deadlock errors before, and Django/Postgres usually throw an explicit deadlock error, which I can then catch and use to retry the operation. But some of these having been waiting for a over 12 hours.

Could my use of pgbouncer causing transactions to remain open, thus preventing the lock on my table from being released?

Querying pg_locks explicitly shows several exclusive locks on my table, as well as several stalled processes:

```
SELECT  relation::regclass,
    locktype,
    pid,
    mode,
    granted
FROM pg_locks
WHERE relation::regclass::varchar like 'myapp_job';
```

which shows me:

```
+-----------+----------+-------+------------------+---------+
| relation  | locktype |  pid  |       mode       | granted |
+-----------+----------+-------+------------------+---------+
| myapp_job | relation |  1995 | AccessShareLock  | t       |
| myapp_job | relation |  1995 | RowExclusiveLock | t       |
| myapp_job | tuple    | 31497 | ExclusiveLock    | t       |
| myapp_job | relation |  5773 | AccessShareLock  | t       |
| myapp_job | relation |  1904 | AccessShareLock  | t       |
| myapp_job | relation |  1904 | RowExclusiveLock | t       |
| myapp_job | relation |  1858 | AccessShareLock  | t       |
| myapp_job | relation |  1858 | RowExclusiveLock | t       |
| myapp_job | relation | 32348 | RowShareLock     | t       |
| myapp_job | relation | 31497 | RowShareLock     | t       |
| myapp_job | tuple    |  1995 | ExclusiveLock    | f       |
| myapp_job | tuple    | 32348 | ExclusiveLock    | f       |
| myapp_job | tuple    |  1858 | ExclusiveLock    | f       |
| myapp_job | tuple    |  1904 | ExclusiveLock    | f       |
| myapp_job | tuple    |  1950 | ExclusiveLock    | f       |
| myapp_job | relation |  1950 | AccessShareLock  | t       |
| myapp_job | relation |  1950 | RowExclusiveLock | t       |
| myapp_job | relation |  5731 | AccessShareLock  | t       |
| myapp_job | relation |  5731 | RowShareLock     | t       |
+-----------+----------+-------+------------------+---------+
```

Joining pg_lock onto pg_stat_activity shows me which queries are causing the deadlock:

```
SELECT  pl.relation::regclass,
    pl.locktype,
    pl.pid,
    pl.mode,
    pl.granted,
    pa.query_start,
    pa.current_query as query___________________________________
FROM pg_locks as pl
inner join pg_stat_activity as pa on pa.procpid = pl.pid
WHERE pl.relation::regclass::varchar like 'myapp_job'
order by pa.query_start;
```

which gives me:

```
+-----------+----------+------+------------------+---------+-------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| relation  | locktype | pid  |       mode       | granted |          query_start          |                              query                              |
+-----------+----------+------+------------------+---------+-------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| myapp_job | relation | 5731 | AccessShareLock  | t       | 2014-02-28 00:00:01.936118-05 | <IDLE> in transaction                                           |
| myapp_job | relation | 5731 | RowShareLock     | t       | 2014-02-28 00:00:01.936118-05 | <IDLE> in transaction                                           |
| myapp_job | relation | 5773 | AccessShareLock  | t       | 2014-02-28 07:33:37.967912-05 | <IDLE> in transaction                                           |
| myapp_job | tuple    | 3867 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | 2014-02-28 10:46:47.363178-05 | UPDATE myapp_job SET is_running = true WHERE myapp_job.id = 32  |
| myapp_job | relation | 3867 | RowExclusiveLock | t       | 2014-02-28 10:46:47.363178-05 | UPDATE myapp_job SET is_running = true WHERE myapp_job.id = 32  |
| myapp_job | relation | 3867 | AccessShareLock  | t       | 2014-02-28 10:46:47.363178-05 | UPDATE myapp_job SET is_running = true WHERE myapp_job.id = 32  |
| myapp_job | tuple    | 3893 | ExclusiveLock    | f       | 2014-02-28 10:47:01.860486-05 | UPDATE myapp_job SET is_running = true WHERE myapp_job.id = 32  |
| myapp_job | relation | 3893 | AccessShareLock  | t       | 2014-02-28 10:47:01.860486-05 | UPDATE myapp_job SET is_running = true WHERE myapp_job.id = 32  |
| myapp_job | relation | 3893 | RowExclusiveLock | t       | 2014-02-28 10:47:01.860486-05 | UPDATE myapp_job SET is_running = true WHERE myapp_job.id = 32  |
| myapp_job | relation | 3932 | RowExclusiveLock | t       | 2014-02-28 10:48:02.124961-05 | UPDATE myapp_job SET is_running = true WHERE myapp_job.id = 32  |
| myapp_job | relation | 3932 | AccessShareLock  | t       | 2014-02-28 10:48:02.124961-05 | UPDATE myapp_job SET is_running = true WHERE myapp_job.id = 32  |
| myapp_job | tuple    | 3932 | ExclusiveLock    | f       | 2014-02-28 10:48:02.124961-05 | UPDATE myapp_job SET is_running = true WHERE myapp_job.id = 32  |
+-----------+----------+------+------------------+---------+-------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

As you can see, the oldest ExclusiveLock has been granted, but has been running for over ten minutes just to set `is_running = true` on a single row.
Why would this be?

Comment: Are there any triggers or rules on `myapp_job`? Does the process that holds the `ExclusiveLock` wait on any other locks? (Search for its pid, and granted = 'f'`).